# Regular Expression to find matching between two string

Tags: regex

Looking for reg expression to return matching in .NET environment.

In a string like this...

```
Parameters!param_id.Value && Parameters!abc.Value
```

I'm looking for matching word xyz between Parameters! and .Value

So from above string example, it will return "param_id" and "abc".

I tried ...

```
(?<=Parameters!)(.*)(?=\.Value)
```

But it returns one matching between first beginning string and last ending string.

```
(?<=Parameters!)(.*?)(?=\.Value)
```

returns only first matching word.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Some code to get it going...

```
Dim reg As Regex = New Regex("(?<=Parameters!)(.*)(?=\.Value)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim col As MatchCollection = reg.Matches("Parameters!param_id.Value && Parameters!abc.Value")
For Each m As Match In col
    Debug.WriteLine(m)
Next
```

Comment: Please post your code, your second expression is correct you just need to find all matches (and how exactly to do that depends on the language).

Comment: probably want to use `\w*` instead of `.*`

Comment: Thanks to all.  zzzzBov's answer is good.

Comment: Dim reg As Regex = New Regex("(?<=Parameters!)(\w*)(?=\.Value)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim col As MatchCollection = reg.Matches("Parameters!param_id.Value && Parameters!abc.Value")
For Each m As Match In col
    Debug.WriteLine(m)
Next

Comment: Stand back: ["I know regular expressions"](https://xkcd.com/208/)

Answer (score 0):

I just would try:

```
Parameters\!(.*?)\.Value
```

Answer (score 0):

*Since feature requests to [mark a comment as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82099/answering-comment-answered-questions) remain declined, I copy the above solution here.*

```
Dim reg As Regex = New Regex("(?<=Parameters!)(\w*)(?=\.Value)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
Dim col As MatchCollection = reg.Matches("Parameters!param_id.Value && Parameters!abc.Value")
For Each m As Match In col
    Debug.WriteLine(m)
Next
```

–  sdog